# How to force form_state['input'] to form_state['values']

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a custom form that uses AJAX to add new fieldsets

1. internal users can specify a default set of artists, e.g. 4, and send this to a record label/management etc.
2. the rep can come to the form, and add additional fields (via ajax)

After specifing some of the fields that are part of the AJAX fieldsets to '#required' , the values are no longer in form_state['values'] but still show in form_state['input']

The question is, how do I send the values in $form_state['input'] into $form_state['values'] to take advantage of the drupals form processing?

```
function quickmusic_form($form, &$form_state, $this_node = false) {
// Set default values, if any
if(!empty($this_node->field_heading_text['und'][0]['value'])){
    $default_heading = $this_node->field_heading_text['und'][0]['value'];
}else{
    $default_heading = return_default_heading('quickmusic');
}

if(!empty($this_node->field_paragraph_text['und'][0]['value'])){
    $default_paragraph = $this_node->field_paragraph_text['und'][0]['value'];
}else{
    $default_paragraph = return_default_paragraph('quickmusic');
}

if(!empty($this_node->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'])){
    $default_first = $this_node->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'];
}else{
    $default_first = '';
}

if(!empty($this_node->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'])){
    $default_last = $this_node->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'];
}else{
    $default_last = '';
}

if(!empty($this_node->field_quickform_type['und'][0]['value'])){
    $default_tag = $this_node->field_quickform_type['und'][0]['value'];
}else{
    $default_tag = 'QuickMusic';
}

$form = array();
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION["anonymous-tracker"]=time();
$form['#attributes']['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data';
// Add module form css
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module','quickform') . '/css/form.css',
);
// Add module form js
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module','quickform') . '/js/form.js',
);

//Text
$form['headingtext1'] = return_heading_1($default_heading);
$form['headingtext2'] = return_heading_2($default_paragraph);
$form['headingtext3'] = return_heading_3();

//Contact
$form['contact_info']= return_contact_fieldset();
$form['contact_info']['first_name'] = return_first_name($default_first);
$form['contact_info']['last_name'] = return_last_name($default_last);
$form['contact_info']['email1'] = return_email1();

//Artist
$form['artist_info'] = return_artist_wrapper();
$form['artist_info']['tos_c'] = return_tos_c();
$form['artist_info']['tos_p'] = return_tos_p();
$form['artist_info']['tags_c'] = return_tags_c($default_tag);

// artists_count =  added by internal user, defaults to 1
// next_artists = for end user to add more
// if artist count is empty, set it to 1
// if internal artists is not empty, set it to the count of total internal artists

if(empty($form_state['artists_count'])){ 
    $form_state['artists_count'] = 1;
    $form_state['ajax_artists'] = 1;
    $form_state['next_artist'] = $form_state['ajax_artists'] + 1;       

    if (!empty($this_node->field_artist_names['und'][0])){
        $form_state['artists_count'] = count($this_node->field_artist_names['und']);
        $form_state['ajax_artists'] = count($this_node->field_artist_names['und']);
        $form_state['next_artist'] = $form_state['ajax_artists'] + 1;
    }
}

// This controls the # of artists added internally
// Lets add either 1 artist (default)
// Or X number of artists as determined by artist names via node create form
$total_artists = $form_state['artists_count'];

for ($x = 0; $x < $total_artists; $x++){
    // Grab node information
    if(!empty($this_node->field_artist_names['und'][$x]['value'])){
            $this_artist = $this_node->field_artist_names['und'][$x]['value'];
    }else{
        $this_artist = '';
    }

    //each artist requires a set of fields
    $form['artist_info'][$x] = return_artist_container($x);
    $form['artist_info'][$x]['artist'] = return_artist_fieldset_loop();
    $form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['account_name'] = return_artist_name($this_artist, $x, true);
    $form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['music_text'] = return_artist_music_text();
    $form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['titles'] = return_artist_music_titles();
    $form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['music'] = return_artist_music();
    $form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['remove'] = return_rem_artists($x);
```

}#end artist_count loop

$change_artist = $form_state['ajax_artists'];

// if next artist == ajax artists, replace the hidden artist with a visible artist
// ajax artists only == ajax_artists AFTER the add more button is clicked
if($form_state['next_artist'] == $form_state['ajax_artists']){
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    // get the current #
    // ajax artists are incremented on button click
    $x = $form_state['next_artist'];
    $form_state['next_artist']++;

```
//each artist requires a set of fields
$form['artist_info'][$x] = return_artist_container($x);
$form['artist_info'][$x]['artist'] = return_artist_fieldset_loop();
$form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['account_name'] = return_artist_name('', $x, true);
$form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['music_text'] = return_artist_music_text();
$form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['titles'] = return_artist_music_titles();
$form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['music'] = return_artist_music();
$form['artist_info'][$x]['artist']['remove'] = return_rem_artists($x);
```

}#end if statement

// Add another file button
// When clicked, it will replace hidden artist with a visible artist 
$form['add_more_artists'] = return_add_artists($change_artist);

$form['submit'][] = return_form_submit();
$form['#submit'][] = 'quickjoin_form_submit';

## echo '

```
', print_r($form_state), '
```

';

return $form; } #end quickmusic form

//This wraps the entire artist section
function return_artist_wrapper(){
    return array(
        '#type'=>'fieldset',
        '#title'=>t('Your Artists'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
}

//this wraps each artist
function return_artist_container($x = 0){
    return array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#prefix' => "", #should be different for each artist
        '#suffix' => '',
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
}

//This is for the default set of artists && the AJAX
function return_artist_fieldset_loop($x =0){
    return array(
        '#type'=>'fieldset',
        '#title'=>t('Artist'),
        #'#description'=>t('All fields are required'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );
}

// Add more button
function return_add_artists($change_artist){
    return array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#name' => "add_more_artists",
        '#value' => t('Add Another Artist'),
        '#submit' => array('artists_add_more'), #increment $form_state['ajax_artists']
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'artists_add_more_callback', #function that returns elements
            'wrapper' => "artists-wrapper", #method this wrapper with the returned elements
            'method' => 'append',
            #May be: 'replaceWith', 'append', 'prepend', 'before', 'after', or 'html'
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
 * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
 * This gets called before the call back
 */
function artists_add_more($form, &$form_state) {
    //dont increment if there are errors on the form
    if (form_get_errors()) {
        return false; 
    }else{
        $form_state['ajax_artists']++;
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }
}

/**
 * select and return the portion of the form 
 * that is to be replaced on the original page.
 */
function artists_add_more_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    if (form_get_errors()) {
        return false; 
    }else{
        $this_artist = $form_state['ajax_artists'];
        $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
        return $form['artist_info'][$this_artist];
    }
}

function artists_rem_more($form, &$form_state) {
    //dont increment if there are errors on the form
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function return_rem_artists($this_artist){
    return array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('X'),
        #'#submit' => array('artists_rem_more'), #increment $form_state['artists_count']
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'return_rem_artist', #function that returns elements
            'wrapper' => "artist{$this_artist}", #replace this wrapper with the returned elements
            'method' => 'replaceWith',
            #May be: 'replaceWith', 'append', 'prepend', 'before', 'after', or 'html'
        ),
    );
}

/**
 *this gets replaced via the add more callback
 */
function return_hidden_artist($change_artist){
    return array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#name' => "artist{$change_artist}",
        '#prefix' => "", #should be incremented
        '#suffix' => '',
    );
}

function return_rem_artist(){
    return array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#name' => "deleted",
    );
}